# Bean Factory Lazy Initialization vs ApplicationContext Eager Initialization

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

After studying Spring, I learned about Bean Factory, a spring IoC container, and Application Context, which inherited it. One of the differences between the two was that Bean Factory uses Lazy Initialization, while Application Context uses Eager Initialization. But what are the benefits of Eager Initialization over Lazy Initialization?